# BitBucket API Call for Creating Pull Request

Tags: json, rest, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I am having some issues assigning reviewers to a BitBucket pull request. I can create the pull request just fine, but only one of the users is being assigned as a reviewer. Only the last "user" in the attached json payload is being added. All documentation I can find on this indicates this is the way to assign multiple reviewers, however it does not surprise me as the "name" field is a duplicate key.

```
{
       "title": "Test",
       "description": "INSERT CHANGES HERE",
       "fromRef": {
           "id": "refs/heads/THIS_IS_A_TEST",
           "repository": {
               "slug": "fpt-programs",
               "name": "None",
               "project": {"key": "MTES"}
           }
       },
       "toRef": {
           "id": "refs/heads/master",
           "repository": {
               "slug": "fpt-programs",
               "name": "None",
               "project": {"key": "MTES"}
           }
       },
       "locked": false,
       "reviewers": [
       {
           "user": {
               "name": "mattmaur"
            },
           "user": {
               "name": "robsh"
            }
        }
    ]
  }
```

I have attempted formatting the "reviewers" value into a list, dictionary, etc. to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved. The following payload will create a pull request with 2 reviewers.

```
{
"title": "Test",
"description": "INSERT CHANGES HERE",
"fromRef": {
    "id": "refs/heads/THIS_IS_A_TEST",
    "repository": {
        "slug": "fpt-programs",
        "name": "None",
        "project": {
            "key": "MTES"
        }
    }
},
"toRef": {
    "id": "refs/heads/master",
    "repository": {
        "slug": "fpt-programs",
        "name": "None",
        "project": {
            "key": "MTES"
        }
    }
},
"locked": false,
"reviewers": [{
        "user": {
            "name": "robsh",
            "emailAddress": "_EMAIL_",
            "id": 2079,
            "displayName": "_NAME_",
            "active": true,
            "slug": "robsh",
            "type": "NORMAL",
            "links": {
                "self": [{
                        "href": "https://_URL_/users/robsh"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "role": "REVIEWER",
        "approved": false,
        "status": "UNAPPROVED"
    }, {
        "user": {
            "name": "mattmaur",
            "emailAddress": "_EMAIL_",
            "id": 1901,
            "displayName": "_NAME",
            "active": true,
            "slug": "mattmaur",
            "type": "NORMAL",
            "links": {
                "self": [{
                        "href": "https://_URL_/users/mattmaur"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "role": "REVIEWER",
        "approved": false,
        "status": "UNAPPROVED"
    }
]
```

}